# SQL:Query syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

```
SELECT checkIn,checkOut
FROM TIMESTAMP
WHERE UId='2'
  AND checkIn >= CONVERT(datetime, '2014-07-10')
  AND checkIn <= CONVERT(datetime,'2014-07-23 23:59:59')
```

This query produces a syntax error near '2014-07-10') AND checkIn <= CONVERT(datetime,'2014-07-23 23:59:59'). Basically I just wanted to get the values of checkIn between these 2 dates. Am I missing something in my query?

Comment: If, as per your tag, you're using [tag:mysql], you're not using it right. Here are the docs for mysql's [CAST and CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). You seem to be using SQL Server's `CONVERT` syntax.

Comment: Also, be careful because if you were using MySQL 5.6 you could be missing a second in the query due to fractional seconds.

Comment: Not sure if this is what jynus is referring to, but using a semi-open interval would make this a lot cleaner to read - `checkIn >= '2014-07-10' AND checkIn < '2014-07-24'`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring about. Not only clear, you may miss values like: '2014-07-23 23:59:59.5' if your data types is datetime(_non zero integer_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of CONVERT is `CONVERT('2014-07-23 23:59:59' using utf8)` and is used to convert the character set of a string, not perform casts.

If checkIn is a datetime value, you can just use

```
SELECT checkIn,checkOut
FROM TIMESTAMP
WHERE UId='2'
  AND checkIn BETWEEN '2014-07-10' AND '2014-07-23 23:59:59'
```

**UPDATE**: It seems reading the manual that it can be used for casting, but the order of parameters is incorrect in your example.

Comment: Oh thank you! It works now. Now I can move onto my next problem.